# Assign a custom label value to the SQL dropdown widget in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I developed an SQL dropdown widget using guidance from the [Databricks documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/widgets#databricks-widget-example). Currently, the dropdown label is configured as "state" in the following query. However, my intention is to change it to "US States"

```
CREATE WIDGET DROPDOWN state DEFAULT "CA" CHOICES SELECT * FROM (VALUES ("CA"), ("IL"), ("MI"), ("NY"), ("OR"), ("VA"));
```

While I've successfully identified the option to achieve this using Python as below:

```
dbutils.widgets.dropdown("state", "CA", ["CA", "IL", "MI", "NY", "OR", "VA"], "US States");
```

[image: Dropdown widget - assign label value]

I'm facing challenge in implementing the change using SQL. Could someone provide insights on how to assign the dropdown label effectively?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rename the widget using SQL
I tried to rename the widget name using the below SQL command

```
%sql
ALTER WIDGET DROPDOWN UNITED_STATES_OF_AMERICA RENAME TO New_US_States;
```

The keyword "WIDGET" is not recognized in the context of SQL engine.

So you can try an alternative workaround
I have created below an example:

I have created a widget name **US_States**

```
%sql
CREATE WIDGET DROPDOWN US_States DEFAULT "CA" CHOICES SELECT * FROM (VALUES ("CA"), ("IL"), ("MI"), ("NY"), ("OR"), ("VA"));
```

**Remove commands:**

**Python:**

```
dbutils.widgets.remove("US_States")
dbutils.widgets.removeAll()
```

**SQL:**

```
REMOVE WIDGET US_States
```

**Creating a new widget:**

```
%sql
CREATE WIDGET DROPDOWN UNITED_STATES_OF_AMERICA DEFAULT "CA" CHOICES SELECT * FROM (VALUES ("CA"), ("IL"), ("MI"), ("NY"), ("OR"), ("VA"));
```

[image]

Comment: Using Python, I'm able to set custom label contains space. But which is not doable using SQL. In your sample too the label doesn't have the space.

Comment: Yes, I understand the direct approach in SQL is not available.
that is why I have used the remove and created the new widget